# Why I can't import js file inside the html file, it's problem with MIME type?

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error: `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:53134/home.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` when I reload home page with following code(home.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="output.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body class="screen">
  <div class="navBar">
    <a href='/'>Home</a>
    <a href='/wallet'>Wallet</a>
    <a href='/login'>Login</a>
  </div>
  
  <p class="letters">Home page</p>
  <script src="home.js"></script> <!-- this is a problem -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I use  console.log('hello');  inside `home.html` then that is not a problem, but when I add the code in home.js then it appears to be a problem. How to solve this?
and this script(home.js):

```
console.log('hello');
```

Comment: Do you see the JS if you visit http://localhost:53134/home.js in your browser?  Or maybe you see file not found 404?

Comment: There are only 3 files: 'output.css', 'style.css' and '(index)' in browser

Comment: And also 'GET http://localhost:53134/home.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: 404 Not Found seems pretty clear. We don't know what HTTP server you are using or why you think the path /home.js should resolve to your JS file.

Comment: Might be the problem cause I'm using node.js and executing the file with node index.js, or that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: The error message is coming from a browser. It isn't clear what Node.js has to do with it. Did you write an HTTP server in Node.js? Did you write any code to make it respond favourably to the request for `/home.js`?

Comment: Files:
-public
     -output.css
     -style.css
-home.html
-login.html
-wallet.html
-home.js
-index.js
and in index.js I have routes and some APIs:
app.get('/', (req, resp) => {
 return resp.sendFile('home.html', {root: '.'}));
});

app.get('/wallet', (req, resp) => {
 return resp.sendFile('wallet.html', {root: '.'});
});
....
If that's an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on a backend.. I've used `app.use(express.static('public'));` which caused wrong route for js file.. It should've been `<script src="js/home.js"></script>`